Update Status value in SharePoint column based on dates
I managed a list in MS Lists. I have columns named due dates, status and attachment, if the due date is over current and the attachment is empty then the status needs to be changed to past due.
I tried to input the JSON code or automate flow but it did not work, I tried to find a lot but couldn't reach the solution.

Import json

data = {
    "task_id": 1,
    "task_name": "Task 1",
    "status": "Đang thực hiện",
    "deadline": "2024-08-01"
}

json_string = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
print(json_string)


Automate flow



Here are the steps to make the flow:
1, Create a new flow in Power Automate and choose the "When an item is created or modified" trigger for the MS List.
2, Add a "Condition" action and set the condition to check if the due date is over the current date and the attachment is empty.
3, If the condition is true, add an "Update item" action to update the status column to "Past Due".
4, Save and test the flow.
For more information, please refer to:
https://plumsail.com/docs/actions/v1.x/flow/how-tos/sharepoint/update-sp-item.html#:~:text=Automation%20of%20updating%20SharePoint%20list,Item%20action%20from%20Plumsail%20Actions
